# How to set distinct <leader> for a distinct vim plugin

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin, neovim

I have conflicts between the default key mappings of plugin jedi-vim and my customized key mapping.

```
" I mapped some cscope functions like below
nnoremap <leader>g :cscope find g  <c-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr><cr>
nnoremap <leader>d :cscope find d  <c-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr><cr>
```

However, this key binding is overridden by the key binding of `g:jedi#goto_assignments_command` and in `g:jedi#goto_command` jedi-vim.

I am wondering if it is possible to set a distinct `<leader>` for jedi-vim only instead of re-mapping conflicted keys.

Comment: i don't think it that this is possible. What is possible tough is to overwrite the jedi mappings with your mappings.

Comment: Another option would be to change all your leader defined mappings to your actual leader key. Then change leader to something else for jedi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently jedi-vim doesn't use the canonical `<Plug>`-mappings, but separate configuration variables. Nonetheless

```
let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = ",g"
let g:jedi#goto_command = ",d"
```

in your `~/.vimrc` (i.e. before jedi-vim is sourced) should do the trick, and this is what I would recommend.

#### Alternative

The `<Leader>` key is influenced by the `mapleader` variable. From [`:help <Leader>`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#<Leader>):

> Note that the value of "mapleader" is used at the moment the mapping is
>   defined.  Changing "mapleader" after that has no effect for already defined
>   mappings.

So, you could also solve it this way:

```
let mapleader = ','
runtime! plugin/jedi.vim
unlet mapleader
```

Plugin managers or installing as a *pack plugin* further complicate this, and it changes the ordering of plugin initialization. I do not recommend this.

Comment: Following Ingo answer. I remaped most used fcns in jedi-vim docu:
`:let g:jedi#goto_command = ",jd"`
`:let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = ",jg"`
`:let g:jedi#usages_command = ",jn"`
`:let g:jedi#rename_command = ",jr"`
`" will auto-create next visual-map: ,jr  *@:call jedi#rename_visual()<CR>`
`" rename_command() fails in normal-mode, but success in visual-mode !`
`:let g:jedi#goto_stubs_command = ",js"`
`:let g:jedi#documentation_command = ",jK"`
                                                                          
`" <C-Space>`
`:let g:jedi#completions_command = "<C-J>"`

Answer (score 0):

Follow @[Ingo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813602/ingo-karkat) answer. I remaped most used functions in [jedi-vim docu](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/blob/master/doc/jedi-vim.txt):

```
:let g:jedi#goto_command = ",jd"
:let g:jedi#goto_assignments_command = ",jg"
:let g:jedi#usages_command = ",jn"
:let g:jedi#rename_command = ",jr"
" will auto-create next visual-map: ,jr  *@:call jedi#rename_visual()<CR>
" rename_command() fails in normal-mode, but success in visual-mode !
:let g:jedi#goto_stubs_command = ",js"
:let g:jedi#documentation_command = ",jK"
                                                                          
" s  <C-Space>   *@'<C-G>c'.jedi#complete_string(0)
:let g:jedi#completions_command = "<C-J>"
                                              
" jedi-vim Plug called AFTER remaping its commands only
Plug 'davidhalter/jedi-vim', {'for': 'python'}
```

PD: this should be a comment of Mr. Karkat answer, but still not 50 points.